# Transferring Large Data with UDP protocol

Tags: java, network-programming, udp

I know TCP is better to send file but I have a homework about sending file via udp protocol . Is there any code example in C# or Java about sending file?

I have server-client example to send and recieve message. I tried to send the file using the same way but could not succeed. I may need an algorithm to divide the file small parts and send them via datagram, and I have an idea to put "md5" of the part as header of the array to check if the packet is lost or not.

Here is my try , my server side in java;

```
// 1. creating a server socket, parameter is local port number
sock = new DatagramSocket(7777);

// buffer to receive incoming data
byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
byte []bigByteArray=new byte[1024*1024*1024*1024];
// 2. Wait for an incoming data
echo("Server socket created. Waiting for incoming data...");
ByteBuffer target = ByteBuffer.wrap(bigByteArray);
// communication loop

while(true)
{
  try
  {
    sock.receive(incoming);
    String s = new String(incoming.getData());
    if(s=="finish") break;
    target.put(incoming.getData());
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {

  } 
}
fos.write(bigByteArray);
fos.close();echo("RECIEVED");
```

and my client side;

```
String s;
Path path=Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\aa.txt");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);


try
{
  sock = new DatagramSocket();

  InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

  //take input and send the packet

  byte [] part;
  for (int i = -1; i < data.length; i=i+100) 
  {
    if(sock.isConnected())
    {
      part=Arrays.copyOfRange(data,i+1,i+100 );
    }
    else i=i-100;
  }   
  byte [] f="finish".getBytes();
  DatagramPacket finalpac = new DatagramPacket(f ,f.length , host , port);

  sock.send(finalpac);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'Could not succeed' is not a problem description.

Comment: I am sorry for my wrong phrase, I got no complier error while trying this code , but I got no input as well. I just wrote what I tried to do to send file via UDP.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

- The following isn't correct:

  ```
  sock.receive(incoming);
  String s = new String(incoming.getData());
  ```

  The final line should be

  ```
  String s = new String(incoming.getData(), incoming.getOffset(), incoming.getLength());
  ```

  and if you aren't receiving text you shouldn't be converting the data to a `String` at all.
- Remove the `sock.isConnected()` test. `DatagramSockets` are not usually connected, and you certainly haven't connected this one.
- The loop in which this is embedded does nothing useful. You are only sending the word "finish".

Comment: So is my way a correct way to send file after I fix the wrong parts? , or do you suggest another way to send file via UDP? Since UDP is not good to send file , I can not find many sources about it.